# How can I see only my interesting tags in Stack Overflow's list of questions?

Tags: support, user-interface, tag-watching, preferences

As you know, in your user preferences, you can hide ignored tags. This is good, but I don't want to put all the tags I am not interested in. Perhaps there are too many in total, or perhaps I am only fan of one theme and nothing more than that.

I just want to see all the questions in "yellow", the ones I have marked as interesting.

(I hope people don't make strange reflections about the dangers of doing this, it is pure knowledge and having more options).

Answer (score 9):

I will do this in Firefox.

You have to install Stylish, which is a great extension to make little css hacks:
https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/2108

I use this extension normally when something in a website doesn't interest me (for example, for gmail etc...).

Then we will create a style in this program:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
#question .question-summary.tagged-ignored, #question .question-summary,
#mainbar .question-summary.tagged-ignored, #mainbar .question-summary
{
display:none
}

#question .question-summary.tagged-interesting,
#mainbar .question-summary.tagged-interesting
{
display:block !important;
}
}
@-moz-document url-prefix("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/") {

#question .question-summary
{
display:block !important;
}
}
```

Edit: As Sam Hasler suggests, I have created one style in userstyles.org:
http://userstyles.org/styles/12432

(I suppose people of Stackoverflow don't mind the use of Stylish!!!;-) )

Comment: Why not added it to http://userstyles.org/ and link to it there so that it's easier to install.

Answer (score 7):

To be honest, I'm a bit confused by all this.

It seems obvious to me that people have only a small set of questions they're interested in.  Ever.

That is, if I'm a .NET developer, I'll never be interested in questions about COBOL, or Ada, or Objective C.

Would seem obvious to me to show only the type of questions you're interested in by default, and show only the others if you specifically choose it.

I find it very difficult to find questions I want to try to help answer.  Most of the unanswered questions that come I have no knowledge of, nor interest in, and I don't want to have to wade through pages to find stuff that might be relevant.

Actually, going further, would be nice if one could groups tags, and have a little set of group-tags, and be able to click on them-  then one could see all questions about [google-analytics] and [seo] or something, as tags tend to be related for you, but not necessarily in the way that StackExchange assumes.

Comment: Not everyone is as closed-minded. People like to read the answers to questions about technologies that they might not necessarily know anything about just so that they can *learn* something new.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm not arguing exactly that one would never want to see stuff about C++ templates, even if you never use C++; but surely the default would be what one is interested in on a day-to-day basis, and then things outside your experience would be something one would specifically look for?

Comment: Then add the things you don't care about to your list of "Ignored Tags". The homepage already has extensive customizations applied to ensure that the questions you see are targeted to your specific interests, including your favorite tags and the questions you most frequently answer.

Comment: Well, yes, but the list of things I'm not interested in is potentially endless.  To me, it seems a strange, backward way of thinking about things.  You don't go into a shop and have the assistant ask you hundreds of questions about the products you don't want.  You ask them if they have the thing you do want.

Comment: +1, I'm losing the signal in the noise and answering less and less questions each week.

Comment: Yeah, I want to be helpful by easily seeing questions I am likely to know the answer to, but I don't really have a lot of time to sort through finding things that might be relevant.  A pity, it's a great community resource and I'd like to put more back into it.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd seen this before but can't find it now. if this can be edited/linked to an official duplicate please do!

You can use https://stackexchange.com/  - at the top there's "tagged questions" then you edit your "My Tags" to include your favourite tags, you then can view the recent activity, newest, and 'no answers' tabs as usual - and it only includes the tags you want to

I think you can also filter by site, as well though haven't really got to grips with the filters as I quite like to see random questions on other sites I wouldn't normally see!